# Problems with my first CPP program - header and source

Tags: c++, oop

Im spending my saturday night not dressed up for halloween but rather sitting trying to learn CPP :D

anyways could someone please help me, Below I have included my source code, basically when I try compiling this form the terminal I'm getting a lot of errors, basically stating that the variables "name, ho, etc" are not declared, yet I have included my header file, so could someone pleas shave a look at this and maybe tell me what is missing? Thank you so much in advance guys!

```
#ifndef __TPLAYER__
#define __TPLAYER__ //prevent multiple #includes

TPlayer
{
    private:
        char name;
        int hp;
        int dmg;
        int wep;

    public:
        TPlayer(void);
        ~TPlayer(void);
        //Naming
        void SetName(char *_name);
        char GetName(void);
        //Health
        void SetHealth(int *_hp);
        int GetHealth(void);
        //Damage
        int SetDamage(int *_dmp)
        //Weapon
        void SetWeapon(int *_wep);
        int GetWeapon(void);
};

#endif /* TPlayer.h */
```

and here is my source file:

```
#include "TPlayer.h"

/////////////////
// Constructor
/////////////////
TPlayer::TPlayer(void)
{
    name = "";
    hp = 0;
    dmg = 0;
    wep = 0;
}
///////////////////
// Destructor
///////////////////
~TPlayer::TPlayer()
{
    delete name;
    delete hp;
    delete dmg;
    delete wep;
}


///////////////////
//     Naming
///////////////////
void SetName(char *_name)
{
    name = _name;
}
char GetName(void)
{
    return *name;
}
```

And so forth, yet its telling me that for example, name etc has not been as shown below:

```
TPlayer.h:4: error: function definition does not declare parameters
TPlayer.cpp:6: error: ‘TPlayer’ has not been declared
TPlayer.cpp:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘TPlayer’ with no type
TPlayer.cpp: In function ‘int TPlayer()’:
TPlayer.cpp:8: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
TPlayer.cpp:9: error: ‘hp’ was not declared in this scope
TPlayer.cpp:10: error: ‘dmg’ was not declared in this scope
TPlayer.cpp:11: error: ‘wep’ was not declared in this scope
TPlayer.cpp: At global scope:
TPlayer.cpp:16: error: expected class-name before ‘::’ token
TPlayer.cpp: In function ‘void SetName(char*)’:
TPlayer.cpp:30: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
TPlayer.cpp: In function ‘char GetName()’:
```

Comment: You should tell us what command you're using to compile

Comment: You don't want to delete variables that are not allocated. What lines are the errors on? You also declare name as char then treat it as char*. Maybe also you need "class" in front of TPlayer in the header file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to pick up [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from, as the things you're getting wrong are fundamental to the language.

---

Class declarations need a `class` keyword preceeding the class name:

```
class TPlayer 
{ 
private:
    // ...
```

You need this because the compiler needs to know if you're talking about a `class` or a `struct` or a `union` or an `enum`, etc. Otherwise you end up with lots of errors like you got.

---

Your member functions also need to be prefixed with `TPlayer::`, like how you did with the constructors and destructor. These are needed so that the compiler knows that they are part of the `TPlayer` class.

```
TPlayer::TPlayer()
{
}

TPlayer::~TPlayer()   
{ 
}

void TPlayer::SetName(char *_name) 
{ 
} 

char TPlayer::GetName(void) 
{ 
}
```

---

There's no need to `delete` class members that you didn't allocate yourself.

```
~TPlayer::TPlayer()       
{       
    // These are not needed. The variables name, hp, dmg, and wep
    // were allocated when you created an instance of TPlayer. These
    // will go away by themselves when the destructor is called.

    //delete name;       
    //delete hp;       
    //delete dmg;       
    //delete wep;

    // The exceptions to the above rule are things that are dynamically
    // allocated. For example, you must delete[] everything that
    // you new[]'ed, and you must fclose() all file handles you
    // get from fopen(). If you consistently use the RAII idiom,
    // then you won't have to worry about these "exceptions".
}
```

In fact, modern C++ programs nowadays rarely need to use `delete` in application code. The ["Resource Acquisition Is Initialization" (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom allows you to not have to worry about `delete`-ing things a vast majority of the time. Standard library facilities like `std::vector` use the RAII idiom to manage the array memory.

---

Note that [there are rules regarding the use of identifiers beginning with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). You may need to be aware of them.

---

For the sake of learning by example, here's an valid sample class:

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void Set(int n);
    int Get() const;

private: 
    int n;
};

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo() : n(0)
{
}

Foo::~Foo()
{ 
}

void Foo::Set(int n)
{
    this->n = n;
}

int Foo::Get() const
{
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Really? I'm very sorry ill try this now and post back asap

Comment: Thank you so much btw I really appreciate the help form you Wizards, but do they have to be Prefixed with TPlayer:: even though I included the "#include "TPlayer.h" header file?

Comment: @CasperTheFriendlyHost: Yes. It's to tell the compiler that those functions belong to `TPlayer`. For example, you may have another class called `TEnemy` with a member function that's also called `SetName()`. Without `TPlayer::`, how can the compiler know if you're talking about `TPlayer::SetName()` or `TEnemy::SetName()`?

Comment: @CasperTheFriendlyHost: Again, I recommend that you pick up [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242), read through it and do the exercises, etc. They will cover these kings of things and much more.

Comment: I get you :) thank you btw, but like I said, I'm still getting a lot of errors so could someone please paste up a working solution> if possible?

Comment: @Casper TheFriendlyHost: Nobody here on Stack Overflow can read your mind. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Guys, may I say, please I'm so sorry as I know you wizards have much more technically madness to solve but thank you so much for taking the time to help me, and the above post helps me paint a much cleaner picture of it all so thank you v much :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be `class TPlayer`, not `TPlayer`.  That will confuse the compiler and there's no telling what errors you will get after it is encountered.

Also, your member function definitions need to be prefixed by `TPlayer::`, i.e.,

```
TPlayer::SetName( const char* name ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: OK Guys & maybe ladies which I really doubt, anyway I tried the above and still get the following error:

Comment: can't paste all my errors, won't let me :( but could someone please paste up the correct format for this? please!